# XSL: How can I personalize Content By Query Web Part?

Tags: page-layout, blog, custom-field-types

I'm doing my first steps with SharePoint and I don't have any idea how to show the number of comments of each entry of a blog in a different page in a upper level.

I guess I have to use a "Content Query Web Part". I edited `ItemStyle.xsl` adding the fields I want to add, in order to choose the field in the webpart options using the online editor when I edit the page.

I don't know how to continue. What is the next thing I have to do?

**Edit**

Let me explain the problem again, because I think it wasn't explain correctly.

I have a Site Web with some subsites blog. In order to show the entries in the top site, I set a custom site content type for the entries with the title, etc. fields. With a `Content Query Web Part`, I choose the `BlogEntries` and I use my site content type I set. So in the parent site, I can see the entries. It's different for the comments of each entry, because `Number of Comment` column is not available (I could see this variable on the blog list of entries).

So, the question is, how can I see the number of comment? I thought to add a column into my Site Content Type, but i wasn't able to calculate or search the correct number of comments.

Comment: Where is your page? in same site?

Comment: The same site collection, different "site web"

Comment: Then you have to write custom code for this

Comment: Please, any clue? Thanks @AtishDipongkor

Comment: you can use javascript or c# for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you can do this using REST API and jquery

Make a GET request to the following URL

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('Comments')/items?$select=Title,PostTitle/Title&$expand=PostTitle
```

It will give you response like following

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": "3d7e5b5c-51fe-4b97-918b-70fb47a44f85",
                    "uri": "YourBlogSiteUrl/_api/Web/Lists(guid'5cd08a1c-e3b0-4aef-bfe2-d58f9dc65e2b')/Items(1)",
                    "etag": "\"1\"",
                    "type": "SP.Data.CommentsListItem"
                },
                "PostTitle": {
                    "__metadata": {
                        "id": "3ba5d89b-048f-41bc-8b7f-b5ecec73a935",
                        "type": "SP.Data.PostsListItem"
                    },
                    "Title": "First post"
                },
                "Title": "sdfsd"
            },
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": "3eba0473-0923-432b-9379-7207b681feae",
                    "uri": "YourBlogSiteUrl/_api/Web/Lists(guid'5cd08a1c-e3b0-4aef-bfe2-d58f9dc65e2b')/Items(2)",
                    "etag": "\"1\"",
                    "type": "SP.Data.CommentsListItem"
                },
                "PostTitle": {
                    "__metadata": {
                        "id": "6e7b3cdc-ec25-41c6-b6c2-6fe4482e2ae3",
                        "type": "SP.Data.PostsListItem"
                    },
                    "Title": "First post"
                },
                "Title": "sdfds"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now show your comments using jQuery & HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That it was I was thinking to do but... maybe the perfomance won't be as good as we could expect, wiil it? Is there any other posibility to increase the perfomance?

Comment: @Daniel976034, I did not get your point

Comment: Hello again  @Atish, I added to the description more information about my issue. What I wanted to say before is about the low perfomance of check of each entry from different Lists. I asked if you know other posibility with more performance. Thank you for your time.